# What is the best solution to save big amount files receiving everyday?

Tags: sql

in my application, i receive at least 1000 files per days from different email.
Pentaho i store them in a folder, but what is the best solution to save these files:
storing in folder in my hard disk or saving in a table (sql)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you plan to take advantage of the additional features offered by a sql database, I would advise you continue to store them to the hard drive, and DO NOT forget the importance of backing up your files.

Comment: Ok so i have to save in three different hard disk